# Launch new contentView onClick (to obtain new window from another XML layout)

Tags: android

I'm trying to execute a new `contentView` this way.  What am I missing?  I get a force close `onClick`.

```
    final Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Status);
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just wrong. You can do one of two things here.

**Not recommended but could work for what you are doing**

Simply using `setContentView(R.layout.newlayout)` will set the new `layout` assuming `newlayout.xml` is a `layout` in your `layout` folder

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
}
```

**Recommended**

Create a new `Activity` and set the content in it to this new `layout` and call that `Activity` in your `onClick()`

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NextActivityName.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: so you have to create a new activity? Id rather not have to create a new activity where the content in the newlayout.xml is just strings from the main_activity with buttons that change their visibility.

Comment: You don't have to which is what my first (not recommended) example is doing. It simply changes the `layout`. But then your `Button`, for example`, will be `null` unless you have one with the same `id` in the new `layout`

Comment: If the `layout` is basically the same then just toggle the `Visibility` of different `View`s, change the text, etc...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change layout then try to,
{setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);}

if you want to change activity, then try to intent to forward another activity, and check also to entry of this activity in manifest file in android.

Comment: ok neither of those options worked for me I have a main_layout and an other_layout.xml all I want to do is switch between layouts with a button click...as if main_layout (screen1) has button to open other_layout (screen2) over (screen1) so both activities remain active so that the back button can bring you back to screen 1. .

Comment: when u switch over to other activity then, previous activity on pause state, and when you back then got previous activity on active state.